# Merging a SELECT query and a SELECT COUNT query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table (associations) in MySql with unique and duplicate keys:

```
id | key
 1 | a
 2 | b
 3 | b
 4 | c
 5 | d
 6 | d
```

And I have a table (products) with products:

```
id | product  | type
 1 | product1 | one
 2 | product2 | one
 3 | product3 | two
 4 | product4 | two
 5 | product5 | two
 6 | product6 | two
```

Now I only what the products that are unique in associations and type 'two' so I get those ID's by this query:

```
SELECT assoc.id, count(*)
FROM __associations assoc
GROUP BY assoc.key
HAVING COUNT(*) <= 1
```

Which returns ID 1 and 4 and

```
SELECT prod.id, prod.product, prod.type
FROM __products prod
WHERE prod.type = two
```

which return 3,4,5 and 6

But my attempts to combine these two queries and get ID 4 all fails :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Query should give you the correct result:

```
SELECT prod.id, prod.product, prod.type
FROM __products prod
WHERE prod.type = two and prod.id in (SELECT assoc.id    
  FROM __associations assoc
  GROUP BY assoc.key
  HAVING COUNT(*) <= 1)
```

Comment: Thanks. Having count(*) in the beginning of my select was the course of all my trouble: SELECT assoc.id, count(*)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT assoc.id, count(*)
FROM __associations assoc
JOIN __products prod ON assoc.id = prod.id
GROUP BY assoc.key
HAVING COUNT(*) <= 1 AND 
       COUNT(CASE WHEN prod.type = 'two' THEN 1 END) > 0
```

The query uses a *conditional aggregate* in its `HAVING` clause, in order to filter out `assoc.key` groups not being related to *at least one* `products` record with `type = 'two'`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to select from multiple tables.

> SELECT table1.column1, table2.column2 FROM table1, table2 WHERE table1.column1 = table2.column1;

[SQL basics: Query multiple tables](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/sql-basics-query-multiple-tables/)

`SELECT assoc.id, count(*), prod.product, prod.type
FROM __associations assoc, __products prod´
WHERE prod.id = assoc.id AND prod.type = two
GROUP BY assoc.key
HAVING COUNT(*) <= 1`